# How to use namespace in struts.xml package

Tags: java, struts

My package declaration looked like this

```
<package name="auth_admin" extends="struts-default,tiles-default,json-default">
```

Then my project manager asked me to change the namespace to `/admin`

I modified the package declaration to look like

```
<package name="auth_admin" extends="struts-default,tiles-default,json-default" namespace="/admin">
```

After this all the actions in this package stopped working.

I am a beginner in this field, can anyone please explain on how to get the actions working again in this namespace.

Comment: SO isn't a "please write my code, here are the specs" factory. Show us what you've done so far and we can point what you've been doing wrong, if you provide enough details.

Comment: Here is the solution: [RT*M](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

whenever you specify the namespace it means that the controller will search for the required resources in that particular namespace. So what i think is that you may not have some jsps that you are using in that particular "admin" namespace. So try moving all those resources into that folder.
tell me if your code still not working